# Setting the language attribute when using i18n and Nuxt

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js

I want to make title and description multilingual. I used i18n. In this case, the title gives an error:

nuxt.config.js

```js
  head() {
   return {
     htmlAttrs: {
       lang: this.$i18n.locale
     },
     title: {{ $t('contact') }},
   meta: [
     { charset: 'utf-8' },
     { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
     { hid: 'description', name: 'description',  content: 'Toshkentdagi Old City mehmonxonasi. Mehmonxona qulay, shinam va ozoda. Mehmonxona Chorsu, Xadra maydoni yaqinida joylashgan.'},
     { name: 'description', lang: 'ru', content: 'Гостиница Оld City в Ташкенте. Oтель комфортный, уютный и аккуратный.Гостиница расположена недалеко от площади Хадра, Чорсу.' },
     { name: 'description', lang: 'en', content:'Old City Hotel in Tashkent. The hotel is comfortable, cozy and tidy.The hotel is located near Khadra Square, Chorsu.'},
     {hid: 'hid', name: 'keywords', content:'hotel, mehmonxona, Гостиница, Chorsu, Tashkent'},
     {name: 'robots', content:'all'},
     { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
     { name: 'google-site-verification', content: 'QMHA_lyK1ErrYguS2NoyHKKJC5ohYMGKlV2q4Ei4CPo'},
   ],
   link: [
     { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', sizes: '90x90', href: '/favicon.png' },
   ]
 }
}
```

Comment: `the title gives an error`, what is the error here?

Comment: @kissu a) check version 1 b) please do not translate non-English posts, they need to be translated by the author, to demosntrate that they are fluent enough to take feedback and respond in a timely manner - or to demonstrate their level of language skill, perfect English is not required and the non-perfect English by the author gives everybody an idea of how to phrase helpfully.

Comment: @Yunnosch check version? Editing timeline you mean? Yeah, OP is using a translator for his question (even description). It's not the first time I'm seeing that one, still not a viable reason to close it directly. If we allow only native english speaker to write down here with some good grammar, we will have far less people asking stuff around. These kind of questions are never the easiest ones to answer to, but people still can have some help if they put in the effort. Anyway, your close vote was taken into account, we'll see if there are 2 more people sharing your POV.

Comment: Your comment seems to indicate that you missed most of mine, which proposes how to make participation of non-natives as easy as possible. My close vote I retract.

Comment: @Yunnosch damn nvm haha indeed. I assumed (rather) quickly that you wanted that one closed. I also didn't wanted it to be closed rather quickly because OP still put some effort into his question. But I do second your point here. Glad you retracted your close vote.